# Dealing with dual-account users

Tags: discussion, multiple-accounts

I'm highly suspicious that the user who is posting [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22262893/tweet-button-isnt-showing-any-text-in-tweet#comment33830988_22262893) is the same person as who is posting [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22268527/getting-social-buttons-working-in-rails). The two posts are almost a word-for-word duplicate of one another.

How can we discourage this type of behaviour?

Comment: Flag for moderator attention. They can deal with it. You can't.

Comment: Might just be friends/students/whatever, working on the same thing.

Comment: @Bart: then it's still not kosher to just copy a question in one.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I didn't intend to justify the behaviour, if that is the case.

Comment: You want an easy way to find duplicate questions? Do a search for "down vote favorite": http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22down+vote+favorite%22 (that's the text that gets copied by accident if you select and copy a question). You just need to find the original after that point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this up. This user has now been dealt with, and I think I got all the duplicates (there were more of them) cleaned up.

In the future, simply leave us an "other" moderator flag and explain what looks fishy with the questions or answers. We take a close look at all of these, and have tools for investigating sock puppets.